# Mysteriously, <a> takes 10-15 taps on mobile to function

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I have stumbled across a rather bizarre bug which I haven't got the slightest idea how to fix.

I have the following DOM structure --

```
<div ...></div>
<div ...></div>
<div ...>
    <a href="javascript: alert('clicked');">
</div>
```

**This code works perfectly on desktop and on the Chrome Mobile emulator.**

However, when visiting the page on mobile, I have to frantically tap the button at least 10 times (usually more), and as if by chance, one of these times it works. It's a very annoying bug and it is one I would like to eliminate. (I have tried different browsers.)

Additionally, using `$(...).click` yields the same result.

Curiously, moving the element out of the div (devtools) and into another one seems to solve the problem.

Appreciate any help...

Comment: If you want make a test, give a different background color to this a tag and verify how many pixels are "tappable" from your mobile. 
When developing for touch devices , I suggest you to use a specific framework or be conscious that touch gesture is more imperfect than mouse click and need a wider space

Comment: @Gianpolo I strongly believe that it's not the touch being imprecise. I have the same button (same class etc) displayed at an earlier stage and it works perfectly on the first try. Additionally, I have connected the Chrome Devtools by USB cable to the Android and CLICKED on the button from the Devtools and it still took 10-15 tries, when the first few buttons worked perfectly.

Comment: Are you using plain javascript code ?

Comment: JavaScript +jQuery @Gianpolo . However I don't think it has anything to do with the JavaScript as the anchor itself doesn't receive any input (it doesn't even change color when I click it, by the :hover)

Comment: What about cross browser tests ? Or cross device tests ? It's hard to help you without know your scenario. Even if the same code work in another section

Comment: @Gianpolo As I mentioned, I have already tried using different browsers on the same device. I don't have different devices to test at the moment but I have attempted to use the Chrome Device Emulator and it works perfectly on that. I have tried `Chrome 56.0.2924.87` and the default browser on the `Samsung SM-N910U` and both result in this behaviour.